# NaNs in a function

Tags: r, function, nan

I am trying to run the following function but I get `NaNs` I don't understand my mistake... any ideas?

```
preg<-seq(0.15,0.42,length=100) 
sigma<-seq(0.01,0.1, length=100) 

y <- c(0.1851852,0.4210526,0.3243243)
lf <- function(preg, sigma) prod(dunif(y, preg, sigma))
lf(0.3, 0.02)
```

Thaks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dunif`, the arguments are `x`, `min`, `max`.  According to `?dunif`

> dunif(x, min = 0, max = 1, log = FALSE)

Here, 'preg' is starting as a higher value (for `min`) when compared to `sigma`

```
dunif(y, preg[1], sigma[1])
#[1] NaN NaN NaN

dunif(y, 0.02, 0.3)
#[1] 3.571429 0.000000 0.000000
```